# How can I get Angular structural directive to be dynamic?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have created a base class to create my own structural directives for my project to use instead of *ngIf with conditions. The purpose is to create a state machine that can accept multiple conditions and be reused in various parts of my application. This way I can have change my state and then have the structural directive show interface based on the current state.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Inject, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms"

export abstract class ContractBase implements OnInit {
    contracts: Array<any> = [];
    constructor(
        protected templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        protected viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        protected http: HttpClient) {
    }
    protected updateView() {
        if (this.checkContracts()) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
    protected add(contract) {
        this.contracts.push(contract);
    }
    abstract ngOnInit();

    protected checkContracts(): boolean {
        if (!this.contracts)
            throw Error("Contract not found, please set a rule contract visibility.");
        for (var contract of this.contracts) {
            if (!contract())
                return false;
        }            
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is an implementation using the base class. Everything works fine as expected. When the view is loaded the state is checked and the user interface is shown based on the initial state stored in the state service.

```
import { ContractBase } from "./permission-base"
import { StateService } from "../services/state-service";


@Directive({
    selector: '[course-manager]'
})
export class ViewCourseManager extends ContractBase implements OnInit
{
    constructor(protected templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        protected viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        protected http: HttpClient, protected stateService: StateService) {
        super(templateRef, viewContainer, http);

        this.add(() => {
            return !this.stateService.edit;
        });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.updateView();
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the structural directive doesn't update as the *ngIf statement updates. In other words if I change the state the directive doesn't update the view. That is expected I guess since the ngOnUpdate is only called once.

So the question is, what is the best way to watch for the state changing in the service from within my structural directives so an appropriate update can be made?

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-custom-structural-directive-example this might help

Comment: Can you please create [mcve]?